# Remove milliseconds from time in php

Tags: php

```
$t1 = '00:08:10.38474';

$parts = explode(':', $t1);

print_r($parts);
```

Current output

```
Array ( [0] => 00 [1] => 08 [2] => 10.38474 )
```

Whats the good way to store the time without the milliseconds which is included in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of using `:` to explode, use `.`...

```
$parts = explode('.', $t1);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:08:10
    [1] => 38474
)
```

or

```
echo explode('.', $t1)[0];
```

gives

```
00:08:10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a trick. if it works, let me know.

```
$t1 = explode(".",'00:08:10.38474')[0];

$parts = explode(':', $t1);

print_r($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple regular expression:

```
$t1 = '00:08:10.38474';

if (preg_match('/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{5})$/', $t1, $matches)) {
  [, $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $milliseconds] = $matches;
  var_dump($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $milliseconds);  // "00", "08", "10", "38474"
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/1MUed**

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$t1 = '00:08:10.38474';

$parts = preg_replace('#\.[0-9]+$#', '', explode(':', $t1));

print_r($parts);
```